# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un array concatenado con otros?

Tags: javascript, array, concat

Tengo la siguiente variable `CONCATENACION_GLOBAL` que es una concatenación de varios Arrays:

```
CONCATENACION_GLOBAL = array0.concat(array1,array2,array3);
```

Obteniendo como resultado:

```
CONCATENACION_GLOBAL =[0,1,2,3];
```

Entonces lo que quiero es buscar en `CONCATENACION_GLOBAL` el nombre de `Array2` como sea, es decir, yo estoy intentando hacer que busque mediante un bucle `for` el valor 2 y me devuelva el *padre* para que me devuelva `array2` pero no sé como hacerlo:

```
for(var buscar=0;buscar<=3;buscar++)

if(CONCATENACION_GLOBAL[buscar] == 2)
    console.log("EL NOMBRE DEL ARRAY ES EL :",CONCATENACION_GLOBAL[buscar])
```

Y en el `console` quiero que me salga `array2`, **no su valor**, y no sé cómo lograrlo.

Error al intentar lo de la respuesta:

```
VM404:17 Uncaught TypeError: CONCATENACION_GLOBAL_NEGRO[key].indexOf is not a function
at Object.keys.forEach (<anonymous>:17:38)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:15:41
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tuvieses un número indefinido de arrays con nombres arbitrarios, lo más sensato sería meterlos en un objeto. De esa manera puedes operar sobre el objeto que tiene llaves y valores.

Si declaras las variables en el ámbito global, en realidad tendrías que recorrer todas las propiedades del objeto `window` para buscar si alguna cuadra. Mala idea.

Te dejo mi enfoque para solucionar tu problema.

```js
var array_final=[],
  objetoArrays = {
   array1: [1,2,3],
   array2: [4,5,6],
   array3: [7,8,9]
};

Object.keys(objetoArrays).forEach((key)=> {
  
  array_final = array_final.concat(objetoArrays[key]);

});



var valor_buscado = 2,
    array_padre;

Object.keys(objetoArrays).forEach((key)=> {
  
  if(objetoArrays[key].indexOf(valor_buscado)!== -1) {
    array_padre = key;
  }

});

console.log('el valor ' + valor_buscado + ' pertenece a '+ array_padre);
```

Este código tiene la salvedad de que, si un valor está en más de uno de los arrays que concatenaste, decantará por el último que contenga ese valor.

Comment: De acuerdo, tiene buena pinta, lo probaré y entenderé este finde ya que no estoy en casa ahora mismo. Gracias amenadiel

Comment: No me funciona pues yo tengo esto:

Comment: ``objetoArrays = array0.concat(array1,array2, array3);`` y me da error cuando hago el ``indexOf `` en ``if(objetoArrays[key].indexOf(valor_buscado)!== -1)``

Comment: Me sigue sin salir con tu ejemplo y no sé por qué y simplemente quiero el nombre del array tal como habías puesto... pero me pone que no es una funcion aplicable en indexof

Comment: He puesto el error editado arriba

Comment: Copia el código como lo puse. objetoArrays no es una concatenación de arrays sino un objeto.Tu array0 equivale a lo que, en mi ejemplo, he llamado "array_final". A partir de array0 o array_final no hay cómo saber de donde viene cada valor. Eso siempre debes averiguarlo inspeccionando el objeto inicial